# Oracle: Update field to 'T' based on criteria in subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that I'm attempting to add a boolean flag field to based on an aggregate query. Trying to put this out in the simplest form without providing customer information, I'll call the table MyTable with fields An, Ver, Co, and Rep.

```
MyTable
An     Ver     Co     Rep    NewFlag
A       1      Aa      T     
A       1      Ab      F
A       1      Ac      T
B       1      Ba      F
B       1      Bb      F
B       1      Bc      T
C       1      Ca      F
C       1      Cb      T
C       1      Cc      F
```

I want to set NewFlag = 'T' where there for a grouping of An, Ver, Co, there is only one Rep = 'T', otherwise it can remain null.

I've got a query that identifies the An, Ver, Co where the count of Reps='T' = 1, and want to use a result site like the following as my criteria to update the NewFlag field

```
QueryResults
An     Ver     Co       
B       1      Bc
C       1      Cb
```

In a way, it would be something like this:

```
Update MyTable
Set NewFlag = 'T' 
where
MyTable.An = QueryResults.An,
MyTable.Ver = QueryResults.Ver,
MyTable.Co = QueryResults.Co
```

QueryResults being the result set of my query that identifies those records with only one count of Rep = 'T'.

Outside of using a script to loop through and update records one-by-one, is there syntax where I can just insert my query in to update those particular fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a correlated subquery or `in`.  Something like this:

```
Update MyTable
    Set NewFlag = 'T' 
    where (An, Ver, Co) in (select An, Ver, Co
                            from <your query>
                           );
```

Comment: I tried this suggestion first and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`MERGE` is perfect for this kind of assignment:

```
merge into mytable m
  using ( select   an, ver, co 
          from     mytable
          where    rep = 'T'
          group by an, ver, co
          having   count(*) = 1
        ) x
    on ( m.an = x.an and m.ver = x.ver and m.co = x.co )
when matched then update set newflag = 'T'
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried the first one  the other suggestion first and that worked, but it looks like there's multiple ways to do this, which is great!